# Showing all tabs in action bar sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Im using action bar sherlock and in landscape mode all of my tabs show, but in portrait only one shows.

How can I show all tabs so the user can slide along them? They dont have to be on screen at the same time, I just dont want a pop up menu.

Answer (score 1):

A bit old question and you may already figured out how to fix it, but here's a solution for people struggling (like I was) with the same issue. In fact, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) says the following:

> Note: In some cases, the Android system will show your action bar tabs as a drop-down list in order to ensure the best fit in the action bar.

To avoid the drop-down list when your tab items don't fit the screen, add your tabs to ActionBar and set navigation mode **after** adding the items.

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
//bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); // Don't set navigation mode yet, if you do then portrait mode will revert to list mode if tab items don't fit the screen
bar.setLogo(logo);
bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Add lots of tab items
for (int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.newTab();
    String[] s = channels[i].split(":");
    tab.setText(s[0]);
    tab.setTag(s[1]);
    tab.setTabListener(this);

    bar.addTab(tab);
}

// Set navigation mode now, that will show all tabs in portrait mode instead of drop-down regardless the screen size
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

That's it :)